# actionlistener for a listview item/button android

Tags: android, database, button, actionlistener

```
package com.xpresso;

//import android.R;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
//import com.xpresso.SQLiteAdapter;

public class Xpresso extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener,OnClickListener {

    Button left, right, rg_left, rg_right, lf_left, lf_right,hello,how,goodbye,thankyou,okay,goodmorning,letsgo,goodnight;
    Button maintalkbutton,lefttalkbutton,righttalkbutton;
    private TextToSpeech mTts;

    ViewFlipper flipper;
    EditText main_text,lefttext,righttext;
    private SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;
    ListView listContent;
    SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
    Cursor cursor;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);



        mTts = new TextToSpeech(this,this);
        final Animation b = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade);


        hello = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hello);
        how = (Button) findViewById(R.id.how);
        goodbye = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goodbye);
        okay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.okay);
        thankyou = (Button) findViewById(R.id.thankyou);
        goodmorning = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goodmorning);
        letsgo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.letsgo);
        goodnight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goodnight);



        hello.setOnClickListener(this);
        how.setOnClickListener(this);
        goodbye.setOnClickListener(this);
        okay.setOnClickListener(this);
        thankyou.setOnClickListener(this);
        goodmorning.setOnClickListener(this);
        letsgo.setOnClickListener(this);
        goodnight.setOnClickListener(this);


        main_text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.main_text);
        lefttext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lefttext);
        righttext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.righttext);


        left = (Button) findViewById(R.id.left);
        right = (Button) findViewById(R.id.right);

        rg_left = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rg_left);
        rg_right = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rg_right);

        lf_left = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lf_left);
        lf_right = (Button) findViewById(R.id.lf_right);

        maintalkbutton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.maintalkbutton);
        lefttalkbutton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.lefttalkbutton);
        righttalkbutton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.righttalkbutton);



        listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contentlist);
        flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);

        mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
        mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();
        cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();
        String[] from = new String[]{SQLiteAdapter.KEY_ID, SQLiteAdapter.KEY_number, SQLiteAdapter.KEY_phrase};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.text1,R.id.text2};
        cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);
        listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        registerForContextMenu(listContent);

        listContent.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        left.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                flipper.setInAnimation(b);
                flipper.showPrevious(); 

                }
            });

        right.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                flipper.setInAnimation(b);
                flipper.showNext(); 

                }
            });

        rg_left.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                flipper.setInAnimation(b);
                flipper.showPrevious(); 

                }
            });

        rg_right.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                flipper.setInAnimation(b);
                flipper.showNext(); 

                }
            });

        lf_left.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                flipper.setInAnimation(b);
                flipper.showPrevious(); 

                }
            });

        lf_right.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                flipper.setInAnimation(b);
                flipper.showNext(); 

                }
            });



        maintalkbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //String talkit = maintext.getText().toString();
                String maintextstring = main_text.getText().toString();              
                mTts.speak(maintextstring,
                            TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,  // Drop all pending entries in the playback queue.
                            null);

            }
        });

        lefttalkbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //String talkit = maintext.getText().toString();
                String maintextstring = lefttext.getText().toString();               
                mTts.speak(maintextstring,
                            TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,  // Drop all pending entries in the playback queue.
                            null);

            }
        });

        righttalkbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //String talkit = maintext.getText().toString();
                String maintextstring = righttext.getText().toString();              
                mTts.speak(maintextstring,
                            TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,  // Drop all pending entries in the playback queue.
                            null);

            }
        });


    }//end oncreate




        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() 
        {
            super.onDestroy();

            mySQLiteAdapter.close(); //close the sqlite adapter

            if (mTts != null) {
                mTts.stop();
                mTts.shutdown();
            }//shutdown the tts engine

        }

        private void updateList(){
            cursor.requery();
        }

        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
        {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.layout.options, menu);
            return true;
        }



      @Override
      public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
      {

          switch (item.getItemId()) {

          case R.id.deletealloption:
          {
              mySQLiteAdapter.deleteAll();
              updateList();
              Toast.makeText(this, "Deleted all entries.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

          }
              case R.id.addoption: 
              {
                  AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

                  alert.setTitle("Add to phrases");

                  final EditText input = new EditText(this);
                  alert.setView(input);

                  alert.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    String value = input.getText().toString();
                    mySQLiteAdapter.insert("3", value);

                    updateList();
                    }
                  });

                  alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                      // Canceled.
                    }
                  });

                  alert.show();
              }




          }
          return false;
      } 



      @Override
      public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

        menu.setHeaderTitle("Options");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Delete");
        menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Change");

    }

      @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
          AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
          .getMenuInfo();
          int index = info.position;

            if(item.getTitle()=="Delete"){Toast.makeText(this, "Deleted : "+ index+info.id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
/*function1(item.getItemId());*/}
        else if(item.getTitle()=="Change"){}
        else {return false;}
    return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {

        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            int result = mTts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            //mTts.speak("testing testing",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA ||
                result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            } else {
                maintalkbutton.setEnabled(true);
            }
        } else {
        }


        }//close oninit




    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        if(v.getId()==R.id.hello)
        {
            mTts.speak("hello",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
        if(v.getId()==R.id.how)
        {
            mTts.speak("how?",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
        if(v.getId()==R.id.goodbye)
        {
            mTts.speak("Good Bye",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
        if(v.getId()==R.id.okay)
        {
            mTts.speak("Okay",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
        if(v.getId()==R.id.thankyou)
        {
            mTts.speak("Thank you",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
        if(v.getId()==R.id.goodmorning)
        {
            mTts.speak("Good Morning!",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
        if(v.getId()==R.id.letsgo)
        {
            mTts.speak("Let's go",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }
        if(v.getId()==R.id.goodnight)
        {
            mTts.speak("Good Night",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        }

    }




}
```

This is my main activity.
This is my database helper file 
    package com.xpresso;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "phrasedb";

        public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
                super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                /*
                 * Create the employee table and populate it with sample data.
                 * In step 6, we will move these hardcoded statements to an XML document.
                 */
                String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS insertphrase (" +
                                                "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                                                "phrases TEXT)";
                db.execSQL(sql);


                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO insertphrase (phrases) VALUES ('this is a string')");
                db.execSQL("INSERT INTO insertphrase (phrases) VALUES ('this is a string 2')");


        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employees");
                onCreate(db);
        }

}
```

this is my sqliteadapter.java

```
package com.xpresso;

import android.content.ContentValues;

import android.content.Context;

import android.database.Cursor;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;



public class SQLiteAdapter {



 public static final String MYDATABASE_NAME = "phrasesdatabase_";

 public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE = "phrasestable";

 public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 1;

 public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";

 public static final String KEY_number = "number";

 public static final String KEY_phrase = "phrase";



 //create table phrasesdatabase (ID integer primary key, Content text not null);

 private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE =

  "create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " ("

  + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "

  + KEY_number + " text not null, "

  + KEY_phrase + " text not null);";



 private SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;

 private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;



 private Context context;



 public SQLiteAdapter(Context c){

  context = c;

 }



 public SQLiteAdapter openToRead() throws android.database.SQLException {

  sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);

  sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();

  return this; 

 }



 public SQLiteAdapter openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException {

  sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);

  sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();

  return this; 

 }



 public void close(){

  sqLiteHelper.close();

 }



 public long insert(String number, String phrase){



  ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

  contentValues.put(KEY_number, number);

  contentValues.put(KEY_phrase, phrase);

  return sqLiteDatabase.insert(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);

 }



 public int deleteAll(){

  return sqLiteDatabase.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, null);

 }



 public Cursor queueAll(){

  String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_number, KEY_phrase};

  Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns,

    null, null, null, null, null);



  return cursor;

 }



 public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {



  public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,

    CursorFactory factory, int version) {

   super(context, name, factory, version);

  }



  @Override

  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


   db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE);

  }



  @Override

  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {


  }

 } 

}
```

this is one of my xmls that had the list view for the database

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal" android:background="@drawable/bbg" >

   <TableRow android:layout_height="80px" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">

<Button android:id="@+id/lf_left" android:text="Previous" android:layout_width="0dip" android:height="60px" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/custom_button"></Button>
<Button android:id="@+id/lf_right" android:text="Next" android:layout_width="0dip" android:height="60px" android:layout_weight="1" android:background="@drawable/custom_button"></Button>
</TableRow>




<TableRow android:paddingTop="20px" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="200px" android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">
<EditText

   android:id="@+id/lefttext"

   android:layout_width="300px"

   android:layout_height="wrap_content"

   />

</TableRow>
<TableRow android:paddingTop="5px" android:paddingBottom="20px" android:width="100px" android:layout_height="200px" android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">

   <Button android:id="@+id/lefttalkbutton" android:text="TALK" android:width="100px" android:layout_width="100px" android:background="@drawable/custom_button"></Button>
</TableRow>


<TableRow android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:width="200px"    layout_height="fill_parent" layout_width="fill_parent">

<ListView

 android:id="@+id/contentlist"

 android:layout_width="fill_parent"  android:width="200px" 

 android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"/>
 </TableRow>

 </TableLayout>
```

this is my xml for each row in the list view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Button android:id="@+id/text2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<Button android:id="@+id/text1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<Button android:id="@+id/id" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

for every button in the list view i want to add an action listener for that button which takes in the text of the button and prints it out or toast. your help would be much much much appreciated.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer !!!!!

```
listContent.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
             TextView test = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text2); 
                String text = test.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(Xpresso.this, "Deleted : "+ text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

whew!
parth_90 you were my motivation lol thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [onTouch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) method has a View parameter which is a reference to the touched view.

```
     public void onClick(View v) 
     {
       Button b = (Button)v;
       String buttonText = b.getText().toString();
     }
```

This will give you the text of the button.

Performing the toast is pretty easy, just have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html)

Comment: so i did listContent.isInTouchMode(); Then in my public void onClick(View v) i added the two lines you suggested but it still doesn't do anything.

Comment: I also tried this listContent.isInTouchMode();

        listContent.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    Button b = (Button)v;
          String buttonText = b.getText().toString();
          System.out.println(buttonText);
          return false;
   }
         
         
         
         
         
        });

Comment: just use the code in the onClick method of your respective buttons like "left","right" etc. It should work fine.

Comment: If it doesn't work I will try posting a better solution in some time. Try doing the Toast also

Comment: I got the answer! i can't post it as an answer for another 4 hours coz i am new to stack overflow I will post soon!